# How to connect veth interfaces to bridge slave ports

Tags: linux-networking, virtual-machines, bridge, networkmanager

This will probably be easier to explain with a diagram, so this is the [basic setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmDew.png):

There are 2 containers **10.0.0.1** & **10.0.0.2** running inside a host machine, and I've also created a linux bridge **br0**.

Each of the containers sees its own network interface as eth0, but the host machine sees it as *vethxxxx*. Looking at the picture in the basic setup, there is no connectivity between the containers.

What I [can do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z2r6.png) easily is to add both veth interfaces into the bridge using **brctl addif**, and they will be able to communicate right away, but this is not exactly what I am looking to do.

What I [want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otBmU.png) is to be able to have more granular control over the forwarding between the containers; to emulate a managed switch on **br0** controlled by the host machine. If these were physical machines, I believe this could be done using nmcli with something like:

```
nmcli connection add type ethernet slave-type bridge con-name br0-port1 ifname <port name> master br0
```

and then connect the cables from the machines into the ports used in that command.

Is there a way to effectively achieve the same setup virtually (like in pic #3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot "attach" a veth interface to a bridge port; you can **make it** a bridge port by adding it to a bridge.

A veth interface is effectively a virtual ethernet cable running between a pair of ports. The way you typically use them in the context of containers is that one end of the "cable" becomes `eth0` inside the container, and the other end is added as a bridge port, so you end up with:

[image]

A linux bridge device *does* act like a managed switch in that you can [configure vlans per port](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/09/14/vlan-filter-support-on-bridge), control stp per port, etc.

Comment: Thanks, there was some visible confusion that u cleared up with this response.